# Get latest added file on folder and show it on a html page?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

**My situation:**

- I have a basic HTML page (intranet) that takes a video and plays it on loop.
- Almost every day a new video gets created and I go to the index.html and change the value of the src.
- The web page is static on a remote display so I need to go and make a refresh to the web page.

HTML Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache">
        <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">
        <style>
            * {
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }
            body {
                margin: 0;
                font-family: Arial;
                font-size: 17px;
            }

            #myVideo {
                position: fixed;
                min-width: 100%;
                min-height: 100%;
            }

            video {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
            <source src="Videos/filename.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
        <script>
            window.setInterval('refresh()', 12000);     // Call a function every 12000 milliseconds (OR 12 seconds).

            // Refresh or reload page.
            function refresh() {
                window .location.reload();
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Updates implemented**

- I've implemented a refresh function that happens every 12 seconds.
- It will show up the new video that I put on the index.html

**Additional behaviours**

- I have seen that if I use the same old file name on the new video it will not show up the newest on the page.
- I need to go and make a Ctrl + F5 on the remote display and sometimes needs to close the web browser and open it again.
- If I used a different filename on the new video, the previous situation does not happen.

**What do I want to achieve?**

- If I or anyone else puts a new file on the folder dedicated to the videos I would like that the page gets that file and plays it.

---

[I've seen here that with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10956854/4459694), I can get the newest file on a folder and save the name on a variable but,

- Is there a way to do this by keeping it just with javascript and HTML? (or with ASP.NET/C#)
- Have you used/implemented something similar (with pictures, documents, etc.)? What technologies did you use?

Regards

Comment: This is quite easy to build with c# and any other server technology. You'll find a lot of existing answers in the web and it makes so sense to repeat all this here. Have you see questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179970/how-to-find-the-most-recent-file-in-a-directory-using-net-and-without-looping, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59593310/streaming-videos-with-asp-net-core-3, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38231739/how-to-disable-browser-cache-in-asp-net-core-rc2,... just to name a few?

Comment: You could also go the web server only route without c# or node or anything and simply disable caching. The answer for this soultion depends on the web server you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Is there a way to do this by keeping it just with javascript and HTML? (or with ASP.NET/C#)**

Plain JavaScript and HTML are client side static code. It cannot modify anything stored on the server. You will need a server side application to handle your video uploads, querying, etc. Pretty much all server side languages supports this feature (PHP, ASP, NodeJS, C++, Go, Rust...)

**Have you used/implemented something similar (with pictures, documents, etc.)? What technologies did you use?**

It's pretty much depends what you want to do. You can go the MVC route to render the HTML code, or going a separate approach by splitting client side and server side code and link them together with an API design.